# Cordova/Phonegap set different device orientation for different pages

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

I am working on a mobile game using Cordova/Phonegap. The game starts off in portrait orientation when you are logging in, however, transitions to landscape orientation for the actual gameplay. I had not experienced any issues with this flow before, but now that I am implementing iOS game center integration in the app I want the various notifications from the service to display with the correct orientation (portrait for login, landscape for achievements during gameplay).

Is there any way to switch between orientations with Cordova/Phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cordova-plugin-screen-orientation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation) to do this.

Install it into your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

Then programmatically lock the orientation as required, for example:

```
switch(page){
    case 'page-1':
        screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
        break;
    case 'page-2':
        screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
        break;
    default:
        screen.unlockOrientation(); // allow user to rotate
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I Using the plugin I am able to change the orientation to one direction, however, I am having trouble changing it to another?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I just wasn't waiting for the deviceready event.